# waiting for component data to load

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working with VueJS version 2 and when I click on a link inside (let's say) **componentA** I call **componentB** which is like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        hey this is pokemon {{pokemonName}} with ID {{pokemonID}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                pokemonName: this.$route.params.name,
                pokemonID: this.$route.params.pokeid
            }
        },
        created: function(){
           console.log(pokemonID); // here is the error
           // here I need to do some operations with pokemonID
        }
}
</script>
```

After clicking the link I correctly see the text *hey this is pokemon x with ID y* but when I inspect the console I also read this: `ReferenceError: pokemonID is not defined`.

As you can see I tried with `created` lifecycle hook because I need to make the operations on `pokemonID` variable as soon as the component has been loaded.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper scope here, you forgot to use `this`, like following:

```
created: function(){
   console.log(this.pokemonID); // Now there should be no error
   // here I need to do some operations with pokemonID
}
```

You are getting the error, because there is no `pokemonID` variable defined in the created function, while there is a `pokemonID` variable in the scope of component, which can be accessed by `this.pokemonID`.